# AndroidViewClient, unable to find a view

Tags: android, android-view, androidviewclient

I am using android view client for testing out the UI. My hierarchy looks like(as seen from the monitor tool of android studio):
[image]

What I want to do is get a handle on the ball , and perform a touch action on it.

However, I am not able to get it. 
I used :

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
print(ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()).findViewByTag("ImageView")
    ) as my python script.
```

And the output says None(but clearly an image view is visible in the picture).

What am I doing wrong here ?

**EDIT**:

When I use culebra -G and click on the ball  , I get this:

> no_id1 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/1")
>   com_facebook_orca___id_back_button =
>   vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.facebook.orca:id/back_button") no_id3 =
>   vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/3") no_id3 =
>   vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'High Score')
>   com_facebook_orca___id_high_score_text =
>   vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.facebook.orca:id/high_score_text")
>   com_facebook_orca___id_high_score_text =
>   vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'29') no_id5 =
>   vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/5") no_id5 =
>   vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Current Best')
>   com_facebook_orca___id_best_score_text =
>   vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.facebook.orca:id/best_score_text")
>   com_facebook_orca___id_best_score_text =
>   vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'1')
>   There is no imageview here.

Also, when I do ViewClient.findViewById("com.facebook.orca:id/ball") , i get None.

**Edit 2**

This is the output of dump -a

> View[ class=android.widget.FrameLayout index=0 selected=false
>   checked=false clickable=false package=com.facebook.orca text=
>   long-clickable=false enabled=true bounds=((0, 0), (1280, 672))
>   content-desc= focusable=false focused=false uniqueId=id/no_id/1
>   checkable=false resource-id= password=false
>   class=android.widget.FrameLayout scrollable=false ]   parent=None
>   View[ class=android.widget.ImageButton index=0 selected=false NAF=true
>   clickable=true package=com.facebook.orca text= long-clickable=false
>   enabled=true bounds=((0, 25), (64, 89)) content-desc= focusable=true
>   focused=false uniqueId=id/no_id/2 checkable=false
>   resource-id=com.facebook.orca:id/back_button password=false
>   class=android.widget.ImageButton checked=false scrollable=false ]
>   parent=android.widget.FrameLayout    View[
>   class=android.widget.TextView index=1 selected=false checked=false
>   clickable=false package=com.facebook.orca text=High Score
>   long-clickable=false enabled=true bounds=((1202, 35), (1270, 51))
>   content-desc= focusable=false focused=false uniqueId=id/no_id/3
>   checkable=false resource-id= password=false
>   class=android.widget.TextView scrollable=false ]
>   parent=android.widget.FrameLayout    View[
>   class=android.widget.TextView index=2 selected=false checked=false
>   clickable=false package=com.facebook.orca text=29 long-clickable=false
>   enabled=true bounds=((1226, 51), (1246, 76)) content-desc=
>   focusable=false focused=false uniqueId=id/no_id/4 checkable=false
>   resource-id=com.facebook.orca:id/high_score_text password=false
>   class=android.widget.TextView scrollable=false ]
>   parent=android.widget.FrameLayout    View[
>   class=android.widget.TextView index=4 selected=false checked=false
>   clickable=false package=com.facebook.orca text=Current Best
>   long-clickable=false enabled=true bounds=((591, 95), (689, 116))
>   content-desc= focusable=false focused=false uniqueId=id/no_id/5
>   checkable=false resource-id= password=false
>   class=android.widget.TextView scrollable=false ]
>   parent=android.widget.FrameLayout    View[
>   class=android.widget.TextView index=5 selected=false checked=false
>   clickable=false package=com.facebook.orca text=1 long-clickable=false
>   enabled=true bounds=((612, 116), (667, 233)) content-desc=
>   focusable=false focused=false uniqueId=id/no_id/6 checkable=false
>   resource-id=com.facebook.orca:id/best_score_text password=false
>   class=android.widget.TextView scrollable=false ]
>   parent=android.widget.FrameLayout

Comment: That View (the ball) is not **clickable**, **focusable**, **checkable** or **long-clickable** (as your dump shows). That's why `culebra -G` does not consider it a target for touches. What happens when you touch it on the android app and what do you expect to test?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dump -a`?

Comment: when I touch where the ball is, the ball jumps. This is the Facebook messenger app, if you want, you can test it yourself. I have posted dump -a

Comment: @harvey_slash Did you manage to beat the game? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem the tag on the image is not `ImageView`.
Tag is set using [View.setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) on you android app but I don't think you need it.

According to your hierarchy you can use `ViewClient.findViewById("com.facebook.orca:id/ball")` to get a reference to such View.

I would also recommend you to use `culebra -G` (see [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI)) then touch on the ball image and culebra will generate the correct line to find the view and touch it.